# Bluetooth not working Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: usb, bluetooth

I am trying to use Bluetooth on a machine using a bluetooth dongle. It works fine in Windows 7 but I am having problems in Ubuntu.

When I go to System Settings, and go to Bluetooth, it is off and says "bluetooth is disabled." When I click the Bluetooth switch, is says it is on but in the box below it still says "bluetooth is disabled." If I exit system settings and go back to it, the switch has gone back to off. There is no Bluetooth status in the menu bar despite that checkbox being checked.

The output of **lsusb**:

```
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 002: ID 045e:0779 Microsoft Corp. LifeCam HD-3000
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 04b4:0101 Cypress Semiconductor Corp. Keyboard/Hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 0a12:0001 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 011 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 010 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 009 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 003: ID 0930:6544 Toshiba Corp. TransMemory-Mini / Kingston DataTraveler 2.0 Stick (2GB)
Bus 008 Device 002: ID 1bcf:0005 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. Optical Mouse
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

The output of **usb-devices | awk '/0a12/' RS=** :

```
T:  Bus=04 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=03 Cnt=01 Dev#=  2 Spd=12  MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=e0(wlcon) Sub=01 Prot=01 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=0a12 ProdID=0001 Rev=88.91
S:  Product=CSR8510 A10
C:  #Ifs= 2 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=100mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 3 Cls=e0(wlcon) Sub=01 Prot=01 Driver=btusb
I:  If#= 1 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=e0(wlcon) Sub=01 Prot=01 Driver=btusb
```

The output of **dmesg | grep -i blue**:

```
[    9.645397] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.21
[    9.645413] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    9.645417] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    9.645419] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    9.645423] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   11.642640] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   11.642643] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   11.642648] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   11.794252] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x1009 tx timeout
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of these commands `usb-devices | awk '/0a12/' RS=` and `dmesg | grep -i blue`.

Comment: It looks like this dongle is not supported by Linux.

Comment: I updated the OP with the outputs you requested. That might be the case but I thought it did support Ubuntu.

Comment: There is a bug report. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1221995 A kernel patch is needed.

Comment: How do I do it? I am not sure how to do a kernel patch.

Comment: This is not that easy to answer here. So it is not supported. It is a regression, because it seems to work on older kernels.

Comment: Do you think I am better off buying a new dongle or patching it as you mentioned above? I will figure out the patch if it will work fine and not affect my system.

Comment: I would buy a GBU521 bluetooth dongle as they just work.  The Cambridge Silicon Radio devices are hit and miss

Comment: This dongle works fine on Ubuntu 16.04 and Linux desktop 4.4.0-112-generic (tested with blueman)